# Can't change the color of the chart with an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, constants, recharts

i'm trying to change the color of my chart according to the price change of the day before (if the price increases put the chart in green otherwise in red). But for some reason the chart don't have the right color.

Knwoing that i'm bulding this with the CoinGeko API. Everything seems to work on the console, I get the wrong statement but the chart don't take the color.

Also i'm using Recharts for the chart and Tailwind.

here's my code

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { XAxis, YAxis, AreaChart, Area } from 'recharts';


    const ChartComponentM = ({data, pricesData}) => {
        return (
            <div className="place-self-center">
                <AreaChart width={200} height={50} data={data}>
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient id="colorUv" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
                        <stop offset="1%" stopColor={pricesData ? "#17ff00": "#ff0000"} stopOpacity={0.8}/>
                        <stop offset="100%" stopColor={pricesData ? "#17ff00": "#ff0000"} stopOpacity={0}/>
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    <Area fill="url(#colorUv)" dot={false} type="category" dataKey="prices" stroke="#000" strokeWidth={"1px"} />
                    <XAxis dataKey="date" hide />
                    <YAxis dataKey="prices" hide domain={["auto", "auto"]}/>
                </AreaChart>
            </div>
        )
    }


const Chart = ({id}) => {

    const [chartDataM, setChartDataM] = useState()
    const [pricesIsUp , setPricesIsUp] = useState(true)
    const [isUp, setIsUp] = useState()

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        
        const getChartData = async (id) => {

            try {
                const data = await fetch (`
                https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=daily
                `)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((json) => json)
    
                console.log("ChartDataMininmal", data)

                let convertedData = data.prices.map(item => {
                    return {
                        date: new Date(item[0]).toLocaleDateString(),
                        prices: item[1]
                    }
                })

                const today = convertedData[0].prices
                const yesterday = convertedData[1].prices

                console.log("today", today)
                console.log("yesterday", yesterday)

                let pricesData = () => { today > yesterday ? setPricesIsUp(true) : setPricesIsUp(false) ; return pricesIsUp }

                // const pricesData = () => {
                //     if(ajd > hier){
                //         setPricesIsUp(2)
                //     } else{
                //         setPricesIsUp(0.1)
                //     }
                //     return(pricesIsUp)
                // }

                console.log("Prices is up", pricesIsUp)
                console.log("Converted Data 0", convertedData[0].prices)
                console.log("Converted Data 1", convertedData[1].prices)
                setIsUp(pricesData())
                setChartDataM(convertedData)
                console.log("IsUp", isUp)
                console.log("Prices Data", pricesData())
            }catch (error){
                console.log(error)
            }

        }

        getChartData(id)

    }, [id, isUp])

  return (
    <div className='place-self-center'>
        <ChartComponentM data={chartDataM} pricesData={isUp}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chart
```

I've try to console log every function or const but everything seems good, I don't know why that doesn't work :/

Comment: `let pricesData = () => { today > yesterday ? setPricesIsUp(true) : setPricesIsUp(false) ; return pricesIsUp }` doesn't look right. Don't set state within the function, just return the value, and then set the state where you're setting the `isUp` state. I don't know if that's the cause of the problem, but it should help.

Comment: how i'm I suppose to set the state without the function ? The if statement excpect a function, im not sure I understand correctly ahah

Comment: I didn't say get rid of the function. The `isUp` set state is expecting a boolean. So: `let pricesData = () => today > yesterday ? true : false;` and then, if you have to do `setPricesIsUp` where you have `isUp(pricesData())` but you may not need to the `pricesUp` state if that's all `isUp` relies on.