# Rechart - I can't change the color of the areachart if true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, tailwind-css, recharts

I can't make the color of the Areachart changing. (I'm using the Recharts lib and Tailwind)

The charts are mapped in an other component. `pricesData` return either true or false for each time the charts is mapped. Depending on whether the value return is true or false, the color should change. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The `pricesData` is working because it's return the value , the error should be in the `<defs>` or in the way i try to change the color. Could you help me please ?

Here's the code :

```
const ChartComponentM = ({data, pricesData}) => { 
    console.log("Price data", pricesData)


    return (
        <div className="place-self-center">
            <AreaChart width={200} height={50} data={data}>

               <defs>
                <linearGradient id="colorUv" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
                <stop offset="1%" stopColor={pricesData ? "#17ff00": "#ff0000"} stopOpacity={0.8}/>
                <stop offset="100%" stopColor={pricesData ? "#17ff00": "#ff0000"} stopOpacity={0}/>
                 </linearGradient>
                </defs>

                <Area fill="url(#colorUv)" dot={false} type="category" dataKey="prices" stroke="#000" strokeWidth={"1px"} />
                <XAxis dataKey="date" hide />
                <YAxis dataKey="prices" hide domain={["auto", "auto"]}/>
            </AreaChart>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've try everything :') I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why didn't you add [all the code from the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371334/cant-change-the-color-of-the-chart-with-an-if-statement) you asked earlier to this question? Did you follow-up on my recommendation? Did it help?

Comment: Yep excuse me, I redid the post because I thought I had expressed myself badly I was going to answer you before deleting the other post! Yes I made your recommendations but it didn't change anything, the color still doesn't change, I don't understand why...